# Create Writable folder in Visual Studio 2010 Web-Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, directory, web-setup-project, writable

I've got a VS2010 web-setup project which works well and creates a virtual directory under IIS for my ASP.NET project.

I need it to create a directory for the logs. I've managed to do this by creating a WebFolder and setting it to be writable. The directory it creates is not writable by IIS.

How can I get around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the File System Editor where you have created your directory, select the directory you want to be writable. In the Properties pane, you have a property called ´AllowWriteAccess´. Set it to ´True´ and this will be installed as writable by IIS.

For security reasons, any writable web folders should have `ExecutePermissions=vsdepNone`.
In the IIS6 GUI control, you even get a warning when ticking on write access for a folder that does not have Execute permission set to None.